# Dual boot Fedora with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, fedora

I have a laptop currently running **Fedora**, how can I dual boot it with **Ubuntu**?

Comment: Have you tried booting with a Live DVD/USB? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you drop an Ubuntu DVD in the drive, its partitioner will see your Fedora install and offer to shrink it to make room for Ubuntu.

One thing you could do is, if you have a separate /home partition under Fedora, is manually set the partition to be your /home partition in Ubuntu, so they'd share the same files and settings.  If you're not familiar with partitioning, look around on the Internet for a guide; it's not that hard.  Just make sure you have backups in case you accidentally nuke everything.

The bootloader configuration should be mostly automatic, too.  Ubuntu will detect Fedora and allow you to select Fedora at boot time, just like you can with Windows.  All in all, it should be pretty painless.

Comment: _Should_ be, but isn't.  OS Prober only detects most linuxes on mounted partitions, so you will have to mount the fedora partition containing /boot (usually the / partition) within the ubuntu installation environment (liveUSB) in order to automatically detect it and dual boot without additional configuration.