# How can I dual boot Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, server, virtualbox

I need to create a VM on virtualbox that can dual boot Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop. Right now I have the Ubuntu Server 20.04, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to add another boot option on the `grub` menu. Any idea how do it?

Comment: The Ubuntu installer will add the newly-installed system to GRUB. You should generally not need to do so manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual boot Fedora with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209839/dual-boot-fedora-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

So I have been struggling with this same issue for a few weeks now. I have managed to place an Ubuntu Desktop entry onto the Ubuntu Server grub2 menu and successfully boot into Ubuntu Desktop.

1. Boot Ubuntu Desktop.
2. Assuming your Ubuntu Desktop installation is EFI, copy the contents of `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`. It should start with "search.fs..." and contain an uuid.
3. Boot into Ubuntu Server and edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and enter;

```bash
    menuentry 'Ubuntu Desktop' {
    
    #place all of the contents of the grub.cfg file here.
    
    }
```

4. Save and exit the file. Then enter `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and/or `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`. Reboot and you should be able to access both installation of Ubuntu on the grub2 menu.

When you boot into Ubuntu Desktop a second grub menu will appear. You can disable the grub menu for Ubuntu Desktop by following the instructions here
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/hide-grub-boot-menu-ubuntu-20-04-lts/